# Adding dropout (tf.nn.dropout) results in Nan

Tags: tensorflow, nan, conv-neural-network

Being a beginner to tensorflow and CNN I'm working on emotion recognition to understand these.

The following code works when dropout layer is removed, however results in Nan when added. I've googled around and came across solutions such as reducing learning rate etc. None has worked for me. 
The net :

```
def cnn(self, data):
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data, self.w_1, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + self.b_1)
    pool = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    norm = tf.nn.lrn(pool, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm, self.w_2, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + self.b_2)
    pool = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    norm = tf.nn.lrn(pool, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)
    list_shape = norm.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(pool, [list_shape[0], list_shape[1] * list_shape[2] * list_shape[3]])
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, self.w_3) + self.b_3)
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden, self.w_4) + self.b_4)
    dropout = tf.nn.dropout(hidden, self.dropout_prob)
    return tf.matmul(dropout, self.w_5) + self.b_5
```

The model:

```
self.tf_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(self.batch_size, self.image_size, self.image_size, 1))
self.tf_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(self.batch_size, self.num_labels))
self.dropout_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

self.w_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, 64], stddev=0.1))
self.b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))
self.w_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([9, 9, 64, 128], stddev=0.04))
self.b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[128]))
self.w_3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([self.image_size//4 * self.image_size//4 * 128, 392], stddev=0.1))
self.b_3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=(392,)))
self.w_4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([392, 196], stddev=0.1))
self.b_4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=(196,)))
self.w_5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([196, self.num_labels], stddev=0.04))
self.b_5 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[self.num_labels]))

self.logits = self.cnn(self.tf_x)
self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.tf_y, logits=self.logits))

self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-6).minimize(self.loss)
self.train_pred = tf.nn.softmax(self.logits)
tf.summary.histogram('weights_1', self.w_1)
tf.summary.histogram('weights_2', self.w_2)
tf.summary.histogram('weights_3', self.w_3)
tf.summary.histogram('weights_4', self.w_4)
tf.summary.scalar('loss', self.loss)
self.merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\joyte\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-recognizer\main.py", line 75, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\joyte\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-recognizer\main.py", line 64, in main
emotion_cnn.train_test_validate()
File "C:\Users\joyte\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-recognizer\Emotion.py", line 127, in train_test_validate
_,summary, l1, predictions1 = self.session.run([self.optimizer, self.merged, self.loss, self.train_pred], feed_dict=feed_dict1)
 File "C:\Users\joyte\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 767, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
 File "C:\Users\joyte\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 965, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
 File "C:\Users\joyte\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
 File "C:\Users\joyte\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: weights_1
     [[Node: weights_1 = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](weights_1/tag, Variable/read/_81)]]

Caused by op 'weights_1', defined at:
File "C:\Users\joyte\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-recognizer\main.py", line 75, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\joyte\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-recognizer\main.py", line 64, in main
emotion_cnn.train_test_validate()
File "C:\Users\joyte\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-recognizer\Emotion.py", line 104, in train_test_validate
self.model()
File "C:\Users\joyte\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-recognizer\Emotion.py", line 82, in model
tf.summary.histogram('weights_1', self.w_1)
File "C:\Users\joyte\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\summary.py", line 203, in histogram
tag=scope.rstrip('/'), values=values, name=scope)
File "C:\Users\joyte\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py", line 139, in _histogram_summary
name=name)
File "C:\Users\joyte\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\joyte\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\joyte\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary histogram for: weights_1
     [[Node: weights_1 = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](weights_1/tag, Variable/read/_81)]]

E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_gpu_executor.cc:637] Deallocating stream with pending work
```

Comment: maybe you feed the value 0 to the dropout placeholder? the value should be always greater than 0 (it is the ratio of elements that pass)

Comment: Thanks! I had copied 0 from one of the programs I found online while trying to understand how dropout works. I've now corrected it as 0.5 value during training and 1.0 during validation and testing.

Comment: I recently encountered the same problem. The API reference says "With probability keep_prob, outputs the input element scaled up by 1 / keep_prob, otherwise outputs 0." so this should never happen even with 0 dropout rate. In any case, I managed to get a NaN result even with non-zero, but small dropout rate, so something weird is clearly going on.

Comment: There is a clear bug in this. The API reference says that `keep_prob` is deprecated, and to use `rate` which is `1-keep_prob`. Hence, if we want no dropout (as in evaluation), we should set `rate=0` which is equivalent to `keep_prob=1.0`. This results in all nan's passed out of the dropout layer.